# How do I count how many files running in a Linux directory?

Tags: linux

I have to list the files running in current directory and display the count of those listed

files .

[root@xxxx ~]# ps -eaf | grep perl

root 16278 16196 48 10:38 pts/1 00:40:19 perl filename.pl

root 16379 16293 0 12:02 pts/0 00:00:00 grep perl

[root@xxxx ~]# ps -AF | grep -i "/var/www/anand/file/sample" wc -l

1

[root@xxxx ~]#

There are 2 files running in same directory "sample" i have to count the no of files the above comment doesn't work please provide any solution.

Comment: Is there a file count on the first line when you use `ls` command?

Comment: The running file is a perl file

Comment: use command `lsof`?. Question is still very unclear. Please rephrase...

Comment: I think you mean "executable file".

Comment: i guess he meant "process", rather than file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fastest / easiest way to count large number of files in a directory (in Linux)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083006/what-is-the-fastest-easiest-way-to-count-large-number-of-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ls | wc -l
```

Or when you need only regular files:

```
$ ls -l | grep ^- | wc -l
```

When you need the number of files that were started from the directory, say /home/user, 
you must use something like:

```
$ ps aux | grep /[h]ome/user | wc -l
```

Note `[]` characters that you can place around any letter in the name.

Comment: I have to list the count of running files in same directory

Comment: Is running file a program that is in the directory? Or is it a program that has this directory as its current directory? Or that is a program that has open files in the directory?

Comment: The running file is in the directory

Comment: @Anand: Ok, Anand, I added the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -AF | grep -i "/usr/local/" | wc -l
```

"/usr/local/" is the directory you intrested in

Comment: It returns the count value 1 if 0 or 1 file is running.

Comment: the result must set -1, when 1 process is running it returns 2 because the part grep -i is actually running with /user/local